# How do I fix a DDE SAS unrecoverable error?

Tags: sas, dde

I have a script that opens Excel, opens a Shell, exports to excel and then saves. I get the following error: 
ERROR: DDE session not ready.
FATAL: Unrecoverable I/O error detected in the execution of the DATA step program.
       Aborted during the EXECUTION phase.

And have not been able to identify if the cause is truly the DDE or not.

I have tried switching the Excel|system to particular cells. I've tried copying and pasting exactly from another script that works.  I've tried adding a pause for excel.  I've also tried this on both a windows 10 machine and windows 7 lab computer.

```
proc sort nodupkey data=output2.SUMM2 out=output2.summary_rc    (keep=refcirc);
by refcirc;
run;

proc sql;
create table output2.rc_driver as
    select  distinct s.refcirc,
            put(s.refcirc,3.) || "_" || rc.PCP_RCIRC_desc
                                as  prefix,
            rc.PCP_RCIRC_desc   as  entity_name
    from        output2.summary_rc  as  s
    inner join  output2.ref_circ_data   as  rc 
        on  s.refcirc = rc.PCP_RCIRC_CD
    order by    refcirc;
quit;
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*                                                                      */
/* Get the number of observations/loop counter.                         */
/*                                                                      */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
%let dptr=%sysfunc(open(output2.rc_driver));
%let nobs=%sysfunc(attrn(&dptr,nobs));
%let dcls=%sysfunc(close(&dptr));
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*                                                                      */
/* Build an array for the referral circle and identifiers.              */
/*                                                                      */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
data _null_;
set  output2.rc_driver;

num = _N_;
m_rccode = 'rccode' || trim(left(num));
call symput(m_rccode,trim(left(refcirc)));

m_entity = 'entity' || trim(left(num));
call symput(m_entity,trim(left(entity_name)));

m_prefix = 'prefix' || trim(left(num));
call symput(m_prefix,trim(left(prefix)));
run;
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*                                                                      */
/* Open Excel for DDE.                                                  */
/*                                                                      */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
;
%macro OpenXL;
    options noxwait noxsync missing=' ';
    filename sas2xl dde 'excel|system';
    data _null_;
        length fid rc start stop time 8;
        fid=fopen('sas2xl','s');
        if (fid le 0) then do;
            rc=system('start excel');
            start=datetime();
            stop=start+10;
            do while (fid le 0);
                fid=fopen('sas2xl','s');
                time=datetime();
                if (time ge stop) then fid=1;
            end;
        end;
        rc=fclose(fid);
    run;
%mend;
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*                                                                      */
/* Open the template spreadsheet.                                       */
/*                                                                      */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */

%macro OpenShell;
filename cmds dde 'excel|system';
data _null_;
    file cmds;
    put '[error(false)]'; /*This suppresses errors that may occur if Excel is already open*/
    put '[open("W:\PI\AQC_Reporting_Production_Process\01 Quarterly_Reporting\Labreports\QEDM-Lab_Utilization_Quarterly\Excel Shell\Lab_Summary_shell_v3.xls")]';
    put '[workbook.insert(3)]' ;
    put '[workbook.delete("Macro1")]';
run;
%mend;
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*                                                                      */
/* This macro writes the summary tab report.                            */
/*                                                                      */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
%macro write_summary(rccode, entity, prefix, sheetname);
    filename data dde "excel|&sheetname!r1c1:r7c1" notab;
        /*                                                                      */
    /* Fill in the heading of the summary tab report.                       */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    data _null_;
        set output2.summ2;
        if refcirc="&rccode" /*and referral_circle_desc=&rcdesc*/ ;

        file data lrecl=1000 stopover;
        put "Blue Cross and Blue Shield of Massachusetts";
        put;
        put "&entity";
        put "Top 10 Non-Quest Diagnostic Laboratories";
        put;
        put "Incurred Period &dateStart. - &dateEndIncur.";
        put "Processed Period &dateStart. - &dateEndProcess.";
    run;
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* Fill in the data of the summary tab report.                          */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    filename data dde "excel|&sheetname!r10c1:r60c7" notab;
    data _null_;
        set output2.summ2;
        if refcirc="&rccode" /*and referral_circle_desc=&rcdesc*/ ;

        file data lrecl=1000 stopover;
        put provname '09'x
        units '09'x 
        unit_pct '09'x 
        paidx '09'x
        paidx_pct '09'x
        billed_amt '09'x ; 
    run;
%mend;

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*        THERE IS MORE CODE DELETED HERE TO SUBMIT.                                                                */

/*                                                                      */
/* This macro writes the detail by Analysis tab report.                 */
/*                                                                      */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
%macro write_analysis(rccode, entity, prefix, sheetname);
    filename data dde "excel|&sheetname!r6c1:r10c1" notab;
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* Fill in the heading of the analysis tab report.                      */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    data _null_;
        set output2.summ2;
        if refcirc="&rccode" /*and referral_circle_desc=&rcdesc*/ ;

        file data lrecl=1000 stopover;
        put "Blue Cross and Blue Shield of Massachusetts";
        put "&entity";
        put "Incurred Period &dateStart. - &dateEndIncur.";
        put "Processed Period &dateStart. - &dateEndProcess.";
        put "Diagnostic Laboratory Comparison Summary";
    run;
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* Populate table of the analysis tab report.                           */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    filename data dde "excel|&sheetname!r20c3:r23c6" notab;
    data _null_;
        set output2.savings;
        if refcirc="&rccode" /*and referral_circle_desc=&rcdesc*/ ;

        file data lrecl=1000 stopover;
        put units '09'x
            paidx '09'x
            dol_unit '09'x
            savings '09'x  ; 
    run;
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* Create macro variables of the analysis tab report.                   */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    filename data dde "excel|&sheetname!r28c2:r41c2" notab;
    data _null_;
        set output2.summ2;
        if refcirc="&rccode" /*and referral_circle_desc=&rcdesc*/ ;

        file data lrecl=1000 stopover;
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
        /*                                                                      */
        /* Bullet 1 macro variables.                                            */
        /*                                                                      */
        /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
        if provname='TOTAL TOP 10 (NON-QUEST) LAB UTILIZATION' then do; 
            call symput("bullet1a", trim(left(put(unit_pct,percent12.1))));
        end;

        if provname='TOTAL TOP 10 (NON-QUEST) LAB UTILIZATION' then do; 
            call symput("bullet1b", trim(left(put(paidx_pct,percent12.1))));
        end;
        /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
        /*                                                                      */
        /* Bullet 2 macro variables.                                            */
        /*                                                                      */
        /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
        if RankFacProv=1 then do;
            call symput("bullet2a", trim(left(provname)));
        end;

        if RankFacProv=1 then do;
            call symput("bullet2b", trim(left(put(unit_pct,percent12.1))));
        end;

        if RankFacProv=1 then do;
            call symput("bullet2c", trim(left(put(paidx_pct,percent12.1))));
        end;

        if RankFacProv=1 then do;
            call symput("bullet2d", trim(left(put(dol_unit,dollar8.2))));
        end;
        /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
        /*                                                                      */
        /* Bullet 3 macro variables.                                            */
        /*                                                                      */
        /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
        if RankFacProv=2 then do;
            call symput("bullet3a", trim(left(provname)));  
        end;

        if RankFacProv=2 then do;
            call symput("bullet3b", trim(left(put(unit_pct,percent12.1))));
        end;

        if RankFacProv=2 then do;
            call symput("bullet3c", trim(left(put(paidx_pct,percent12.1))));
        end;

        if RankFacProv=2 then do;
            call symput("bullet3d", trim(left(put(dol_unit,dollar8.2))));
        end;

    run;
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* Build bullet 4 macro variables.                                      */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
        data _null_;
        set output2.remaining_8_final;
        if refcirc="&rccode" /*and referral_circle_desc=&rcdesc*/ ;

        file data lrecl=1000 stopover;
        if RankFacProv=999 then do;
            call symput("bullet4a", trim(left(put(unit_pct,percent12.1))));
        end;

        if RankFacProv=999 then do;
            call symput("bullet4b", trim(left(put(paidx_pct,percent12.1))));
        end;
    run;
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* Get data except for the total for the top 10.                        */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    data output2.sort1;
        set output2.remaining_8_final;
        if RankFacProv ne 999;
    run;
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* Sort by referral circle and by most expensive $/service unit.        */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
        proc sort data=output2.sort1;
        by refcirc descending dol_unit;
    run;
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* Get the current referral circle and then the most expensive          */
    /* $/service unit. Build bullet 4c macro variables.                     */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    data _null_;
        set output2.sort1;
            by refcirc;
        if refcirc="&rccode" /*and referral_circle_desc=&rcdesc*/ ;
        if first.refcirc;

        file data lrecl=1000 stopover;
        call symput("bullet4c", trim(left(provname)));  
    run;
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* Get the current referral circle and then the most expensive          */
    /* $/service unit. Build bullet 4d macro variables.                     */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    data _null_;
        set output2.sort1;
            by refcirc;
        if refcirc="&rccode" /*and referral_circle_desc=&rcdesc*/ ;
        if first.refcirc;

        file data lrecl=1000 stopover;
        call symput("bullet4d", trim(left(put(dol_unit,dollar8.2))));
    run;
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* Get data execpt for the total for the top 10.                        */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    data output2.sort2;
        set output2.remaining_8_final;
        if RankFacProv ne 999;
    run;
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* Sort by referral circle and by least expensive $/service unit.       */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    proc sort data=output2.sort2;
        by refcirc dol_unit;
    run;
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* Get the current referral circle and then the least expensive         */
    /* $/service unit. Build bullet 4e macro variables.                     */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    data _null_;
        set output2.sort2;
            by refcirc;
        if refcirc="&rccode" /*and referral_circle_desc=&rcdesc*/ ;
        if first.refcirc;

        file data lrecl=1000 stopover;
        call symput("bullet4e", trim(left(provname)));  
    run;
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* Get the current referral circle and then the least expensive         */
    /* $/service unit. Build bullet 4f macro variables.                     */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    data _null_;
        set output2.sort2;
            by refcirc;
        if refcirc="&rccode" /*and referral_circle_desc=&rcdesc*/ ;
        if first.refcirc;

        file data lrecl=1000 stopover;
        call symput("bullet4f", trim(left(put(dol_unit,dollar8.2))));
    run;
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* Build bullet 5 macro variables.                                      */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    data _null_;
        set output2.summ_phys1;
        if refcirc="&rccode" /*and referral_circle_desc=&rcdesc*/ ;

        file data lrecl=1000 stopover;
        if RankPhysProv=999 then do;
            call symput("bullet5a", trim(left(put(unit_pct,percent12.1))));
        end;
    run;
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* Build bullet 6 macro variables.                                      */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    data _null_;
        set output2.summ2;
        if refcirc="&rccode" /*and referral_circle_desc=&rcdesc*/ ;

        file data lrecl=1000 stopover;
        if RankFacProv=9999 then do;
            call symput("bullet6a", trim(left(put(unit_pct,percent12.1))));
        end;

        if RankFacProv=9999 then do;
            call symput("bullet6b", trim(left(put(paidx_pct,percent12.1))));
        end;
    run;
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* Create dynamic text.                                                 */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* Use macro bullets 1-3.                                               */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    filename data dde "excel|&sheetname!r28c2:r33c2" notab;
    data _null_;
        set output2.SUMM2;
        if refcirc="&rccode" /*and referral_circle_desc=&rcdesc*/ ;

        file data lrecl=1000 stopover;
        put "The Top 10 Providers represent a total of &bullet1a of diagnostic laboratory services for the Group's"
            / "members and &bullet1b of cost."
            / "&bullet2a is the highest service provider with &bullet2b of services"
            / "representing &bullet2c of cost.  Unit cost is &bullet2d.."
            / "&bullet3a is the second largest service provider with &bullet3b of services"
            / "representing &bullet3c of cost.  Unit cost is &bullet3d..";
    run;
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* Use macro bullets 4.                                                 */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    filename data dde "excel|&sheetname!r34c2:r35c2" notab;
    data _null_;
        set output2.remaining_8_final;
        if refcirc="&rccode" /*and referral_circle_desc=&rcdesc*/ ;

        file data lrecl=1000 stopover;
        put "The next 8 providers represent a total of &bullet4a of services and &bullet4b of cost.  The highest cost provider is"
            / "&bullet4c at &bullet4d while &bullet4e is the lowest at &bullet4f..";
    run;
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* Use macro bullets 5.                                                 */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    filename data dde "excel|&sheetname!r36c2:r36c2" notab;
    data _null_;
        set output2.summ_phys1;
        if refcirc="&rccode" /*and referral_circle_desc=&rcdesc*/ ;

        file data lrecl=1000 stopover;
        put "The Top 10 Physician Office Laboratories performed &bullet5a of all physician office lab services.";
    run;
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* Use macro bullets 6.                                                 */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    filename data dde "excel|&sheetname!r41c2:r41c2" notab;
    data _null_;
        set output2.summ2;
        if refcirc="&rccode" /*and referral_circle_desc=&rcdesc*/ ;

        file data lrecl=1000 stopover;
        put "Quest provided a total of &bullet6a of laboratory services for the Group's members at &bullet6b of total cost.";
    run;
%mend;

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*                                                                      */
/* This macro writes the report spreadsheets.                           */
/*                                                                      */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */


%macro run_data;
   %OpenXL;
   %do i=1 %to &&nobs;

      %OpenShell;

      %write_summary(&&rccode&i, &&entity&i, &&prefix&i, Summary);
/*    %write_summary_fs(&&rccode&i, &&entity&i, &&prefix&i, Summary Free Standing);*/
/*    %write_summary_fac(&&rccode&i, &&entity&i, &&prefix&i, Summary Facility);*/
      %write_detail_by_pcp(&&rccode&i, &&entity&i, &&prefix&i, Detail_by_PCP);
      %write_detail_by_lab(&&rccode&i, &&entity&i, &&prefix&i, Detail_by_Lab);
      %write_summary_PhysOffLabs(&&rccode&i, &&entity&i, &&prefix&i, Physician_Office_Labs);
      %write_analysis(&&rccode&i, &&entity&i, &&prefix&i, Analysis);


      %let saveAsCmdVar = [save.as("W:\PI\AQC_Reporting_Production_Process\01 Quarterly_Reporting\Labreports\Shields MRI Reporting\&quarter2.&ytd.\final reports new\&&prefix&i.._Lab_Summary_&quarter2.._TEST.xls")];


    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* Save and close.                                                      */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
      filename cmds dde "excel | system";;
      data _null_;
          file cmds;
          x= sleep(10);
          put '[error(false)]';
          put %unquote(%str(%'&saveAsCmdVar%'));
          put '[close()]';
      run;

      data _null_;
rc = sleep(10);
run;
   %end;
    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* End DDE.                                                             */
    /*                                                                      */
    /* --------------------------------------------------------ear------------ */
    data _null_;
    file cmds;
    put '[quit()]';
    run;
%mend;
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*                                                                      */
/* Build all reports on the non-molecular "side."                       */
/*                                                                      */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
%run_data;


/*** ---------------------- END PROGRAM ---------------------------------- ***;

    **************        ****           **        *****
    **************        ** **          **        **   **
    **                    **  **         **        **      **
    **                    **   **        **        **        **
    **                    **    **       **        **         **
    **************        **     **      **        **          **
    **************        **      **     **        **          **
    **                    **       **    **        **         **
    **                    **        **   **        **        ** 
    **                    **         **  **        **      **
    **************        **          ** **        **   **
    **************        **           ****        *****  


*** ---------------------- END PROGRAM ---------------------------------- ***;


Expected results is several tabs of Excel for each referral circle (rc) that save to the location identified.  None save. 

Error repeats several times as follows:

NOTE: There were 336 observations read from the data set OUTPUT2.SUMM2.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.03 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds



NOTE: The file CMDS is:
      DDE Session,
      SESSION=excel | system,RECFM=V,LRECL=32767

ERROR: DDE session not ready.
FATAL: Unrecoverable I/O error detected in the execution of the DATA step program.
       Aborted during the EXECUTION phase.
```

Comment: Has it ever work?

Comment: DDE requires that SAS is running on Windows and in your case that Excel can run on that same machine. Plus it requires that some other process isn't blocking the communications channel.  https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2014/10/14/dde-is-doa/#comment-34520

Comment: Did you ever have working code? Debugging at this stage is pretty painful. I usually recommend making sure your base case is working and running step by step to see where the error occurs, but once you're at this stage it's much harder to do that. But it's still the best way to find the bug. DDE still works just a pain in the ass and not something I'd build today at all.

Comment: As it stands you need to rework this question.  Start by simplifying the amount of code you have pasted until you can make it as short as possible and still reproduce the question.  Nobody is going to try to debug hundreds of lines of code to try and find the line causing the error when it's expected of the poster to do that before posting the question.  I see you're new so perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example